# How to wrap text of one TextView under other Textviews in android?

Tags: android, textview

does anyone know how it is possible to wrap text of one TextView under another TextViews, when all they are located in one line one after another?

Here is an example of what I have and what i need (I can't insert image here):
http://www.imagesup.net/?di=1014121123675

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350616/rich-text-in-a-textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use one `TextView` for all the text. If you need them to have different styles, look into using [`SpannableStringBuilder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html) to build the string and add spans to affect the styles.

Comment: What a great idea! I didn't realize that there is something like this, thank you. Now I need to try it :)