# How can i change the text color on textview with with a specific text?

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, textcolor

I want to change a textview's color with a specific text, for example

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    tools:text="Live"
    android:id="@+id/soccer_statuslive"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:textColor="#2ccc14"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"/>
```

So i want to change the color to red when the text says "Final" and change green when it says "Live"

```
tools:text="Live"
android:textColor="#2ccc14"
```

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350616/rich-text-in-a-textview

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
if(yourtextView.getText().toString().equals("Final"))
    yourtextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
else if(yourtextView.getText().toString().toString.equals("Live"))
    yourtextView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programatically:

```
if(soccer_statuslive.getText().toString.equals("Final"))
    soccer_statuslive.setTextColor(Color.RED);
else if(soccer_statuslive.getText().toString.equals("Live"))
    soccer_statuslive.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

check this dynamic code add in your activity

```
      if(sl.equalsIgnoreCase("Live")){



                solve.setTextColor
            (getApplicationContext.getResources().
           getColor(R.color.green));

            }
            else if(sl.equalsIgnoreCase("Final")){

           solve.setTextColor
          (getApplicationContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (tv.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Final")) {

            tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        } else {
            if (tv.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Live")) {
                tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the button in code by using this code.

```
Button b  = ( Button) findViewById(R.id.*youbuttonname*);
```

then you can check either the button text is "Final" or "Live" like

```
if( b.Text.equals("Live")
b.setColor(R.color.red)
```

Make sure you have added the red color in Color xml file.

Answer (score 0):

TextView tv;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.soccer_statuslive);
    tv.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String text = tv.getText().toString();
            if (text.equals("Final"))
                tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            else
                tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do this programmatically using the TextChangeListener?. Something like

On your Activity

```
    TextView soccerStatus = findViewById(R.id.soccer_statuslive);
    soccerStatus.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if ("Final".equalsIgnoreCase(editable.toString())) {
                soccerStatus.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            } else if ("Live".equalsIgnoreCase(editable.toString())) {
                soccerStatus.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
        }
    });
```